# Google Maps and loading scripts async - how to order the loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

If I understand this correctly, using `defer` will load the scripts in the order I put them.

This will allow me to load jQuery before my own function (because it's lighter and laods more quickly). I load Google Maps at the bottom because it has a callback to a function inside `tv-modal.js`.

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="js/tv-modal.js" defer></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=abc&callback=modalMap.initMap" defer></script>
```

My Js looks like this:

```
var modalMap = {
    map: null,

    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.map = $('#modal-g-map');
    },

    initMap: function(){
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('modal-g-map'), {
            center: {lat: 59.9071401, lng: 10.7711175},
            zoom: 11
        });
    }

}.init();
```

But Google Map isn't happy:

> Uncaught InvalidValueError: modalMap.initMap is not a function

Why can't Google Maps callback call my function modalMap.initMap?

Comment: maybe chaining an object + function is not good practice? have you tried just giving a function name like: `&callback=myfunction` which itself just calls `modalMap.initMap();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`modalMap` is not this:

```
{
    map: null,

    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.map = $('#modal-g-map');
    },

    initMap: function(){
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('modal-g-map'), {
            center: {lat: 59.9071401, lng: 10.7711175},
            zoom: 11
        });
    }

}
```

....you set it to the return-value of the `init`-method of the object above.
The init-method returns nothing, so `modalMap` is `undefined`.

You must return the object in the `init`-method:

```
init: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.map = $('#modal-g-map');
    return this;//<--return the object
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I'm reding your answer ove and over trying to understand this. But I don't. Because if I remove `.init()` and use `modalMap.init()` instead, I get the sameresult as using `return this;`

Why is `modalMap.init()`  working and not `.init()`?  I have to understandthe answer `The init-method returns nothing, so modalMap is undefined`.

Comment: when  you assign a variable the statement on the right will be evaluated completely(in your case it creates an object and calls a method of the object) and assigned as variable-value.   So the value of the variable will be the return-value of the object-method, not the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the way the API fires the function it does not recognize that `initMap` is a function of the object `modalMap` by just typing `"modalMap.initMap"` and hence is not a valid function name. Try to create a function outside of that object like so:

```
function apiCallback() {
  modalMap.initMap();
}
```

and adjust your callback parameter:

```
&callback=apiCallback
```